# Communication between a UIWebView and UINavigationController?

Tags: php, javascript, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a app where users can connect with numerous websites. I have a UINavigationController that displays all the websites. It will push when the user taps on into a webView in a different view controller.

This all is fine, but when the user is done, how can the UIViewController communicate with the app and tell it to pop back one? I have compete control of the php files in the webView, so it should be easy, right?

I was thinking about getting the title from the javascript file every time it loads. If it's a special, then go back? What would be the best way in doing this?

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet. If you could just point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic!

Thanks,
Coulton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by "when the user is done" - do you mean when the user has finished viewing the selected webpage and wants to go back to the list?

If so, you already will have pushed your `UIViewController` on to the `UINavigationController` which is not much more than a stack of `UIViewController` instances. Every `UIViewController` has a `navigationController` property which is `nil` until the view controller is pushed onto a navigation controller.

With that in mind, try calling:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:yesOrNo]`

where `self` should be the view controller you want to pop.

Comment: I am talking about when the connection has been successful. Lets take Facebook for instance. Once they are done and it was a success, it will call the app to popViewController in the app.

Comment: @phpnerd211: I'm unsure what "it" is. How are you contacting Facebook? With `UIWebView`? Their delegates have convenience methods like `– webViewDidFinishLoad:` which you can override to call the pop. Are you using `NSURLConnection`? You can likewise override `– connectionDidFinishLoading:`. In other words, and so far as I can tell, this can all be handled locally within the app.

Comment: IT is the connection. They will log in and it will direct to a php document that will process their information and process some mysql stuff. After it's done, it will then go back? Do you know what I mean now? And I am not sure those methods will work when they will be directed to some different pages?

Comment: @phpnerd211: I really think there's enough in the Apple kit to handle all of this locally on the device. [I've handled logins locally like this too.] But I'm still unclear as to what you want, and it sounds like you might be too. Have a look at the `NSURLConnection` page in the Apple docs if you haven't already. There are Facebook kits openly available too.